# if else statement not stopping issue

Tags: java, file, if-statement, methods, java.util.scanner

I have a code which has a button that gets the input of a text field and then afterwards looks through a .txt file, to see if there is a match. Only issue is it runs through each line and checks if that line matches, which means that both the *if* and *else* statement gets triggered. So lets say the .txt file has 3 lines saying *1234* , *5423* , *8543* and then the input would be *1234*, then the code runs as supposed for the if statement, as the input matches, which it is supposed to. But then it keeps going so it also triggers the else statement which it is not supposed to.

### This is my code

```
public static String input = "";

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        String input = jTextField1.getText();

        File file =new File("file.txt");
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);
            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                String line=in.nextLine();
                if(line.contains(input)){

                    popUp1 pu1 = new popUp1();
                    pu1.setVisible(true);

                } else {

                    popUp2 pu2 = new popUp2();
                    pu2.setVisible(true);

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to `break` the while loop when the if statement happens?

Comment: If not, please clarify *"which it is not supposed to"*, because that is what you wrote the code to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. As you noticed, if the file has lines that **don't** match the input, the "failure" treatment is triggered. Instead, you need to go over the entire file, check for a matching row, trigger that behavior if you find one, and then terminate the loop. Only when you're done going over the file and still haven't found a match should you trigger the "failure" behavior:

```
boolean found = false;
while(!found && in.hasNext()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(input)) {
        found = true;
        popUp1 pu1 = new popUp1();
        pu1.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// If we've gone over the entire file and still not found anything:
if (!found) {
    popUp2 pu2 = new popUp2();
    pu2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want popup1 if the file contains the value and popup2 otherwise.

Note I'm ignoring scope issues with the `pu1` and `pu2` variables and the fact that we've got file IO in the EDT.

```
boolean doPopupOne = false;
while(in.hasNext())
{
    String line=in.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(input)){
        doPopupOne = true;
        break;
    } 
}
if (doPopupOne)
{
    popUp1 pu1 = new popUp1();
    pu1.setVisible(true);
}
else
{
    popUp2 pu2 = new popUp2();
    pu2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do :). You want to show only one message if it is found in the .txt file or if it is not. Add a counter that keeps the number of times it is present in the .txt file. If you want to stop when you find the first match just insert a break; in the if clause, move the else after the while clause where you can check the counter, like this:

```
Scanner in = null;
int count = 0;
try {
    in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String line=in.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(input)){
            count++; 
            popUp1 pu1 = new popUp1();
            pu1.setVisible(true);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0){
        popUp2 pu2 = new popUp2();
        pu2.setVisible(true);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

If you are interested in how many times it is present in the file then move the if after the while clause the same as the pu2 case:

```
Scanner in = null;
int count = 0;
try {
    in = new Scanner(file);
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String line=in.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(input)){
            count++; 
        }
    }
    if (count > 0){
        // count contains the number of matches
        popUp1 pu1 = new popUp1();
        pu1.setVisible(true);            
    }
    else {
        popUp2 pu2 = new popUp2();
        pu2.setVisible(true);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```